# not duplicated common rows when two data_frame merge on one common column in pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe, astronomy

When I use pd.merge(data1, data2, on='plx'), I expect it shows the rows with common 'plx', but it shows each common row twice. What should I do to have only common rows with the same 'plx' but in one row not as double to rows?
Thank you

Comment: plx in data1 or in data2 have duplicate , that is why show two row

Comment: also , please show us some sample data

Comment: Yes but we should have a common column between two data files to be able to merge them according that common column. isn't it???